# Wordpress Tags and Categories show on backend (post edit page) but not on frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories, custom-wordpress-pages

I've created a custom post type 'Projects' and attached a customer taxonomy 'Services' to it. I've set the taxonomy up as categories (I tried tags too and still have the same issue). It shows up in the wordpress admin and I'm able to create tags/categories on a project post. The tags/categories are saved in the database, because they still appear on the post edit page. However, I'm struggling to have them displayed on the front end. Please see code below from my function.php, archive-projects.php and single-projects.php. Please note, that the single-project.php file also includes a custom field called 'project-collection' which iterates through the respective project portfolio images and copy. Also, the tags are not rendered in the HTML at all (when inspecting element in Google Chrome). Thanks

functions.php

```
    // Custom Post Types
    
    function create_projects_post_type() {
    
            $args = array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => 'Projects',
                    'singular_name' => 'Project'
                ),
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio',
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true
            );
    
            register_post_type('projects', $args);
    
    }
    
    add_action('init', 'create_projects_post_type');


// Custom Taxonomy

function create_taxonomy(){

    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Services',
            'singular_name' => 'Service'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy('services', array('projects'), $args);

}
add_action('init', 'create_taxonomy');
```

archive-projects.php

```
<?php

get_header();

?>


<div class="row vertical-align d-flex align-items-center pt-0" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 text-center z-index">
          <h1>Our Projects</h1>
          <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div id="particles-js"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="portfolio" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

    <?php if(have_posts('projects')) : ?>

        <?php while(have_posts('projects')) : the_post(); ?>
        
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <figure data-aos="fade-up">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php $image = get_field('project_main_image'); ?>
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
                </a>
                <figcaption>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php echo get_field('project_name'); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <dl>

                    <?php 
                        $tags = get_the_tags();
                        if($tags):
                            foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
                            
                                <dd>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>           
                                </dd>
                                
                    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>


                    </dl>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>  


        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

single-projects.php

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['background'] = get_field('gradient_class');

get_header();

?>
<div class="row vertical-align d-flex align-items-center pt-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center z-index">
          <h1><?php the_field('project_name'); ?></h1>
          <?php the_field('project_description'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
  </section>

    <?php if(have_rows('project_collection')): ?>

        <?php $i = 1; ?>

        <?php while(have_rows('project_collection')): the_row(); ?>

        <section class="container-fluid portfolio-item">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6 <?php if($i%2 != 0) : ?>order-md-2 <?php endif; ?>portfolio-image">
                        <?php $image = get_sub_field('image'); ?>
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-content">
                        <h2><?php the_sub_field('sub_title'); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_sub_field('section_description'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>        
       
        
        <?php $i++; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    
    <?php 
    // Get Tage NOT WORKING!
        $tags = get_the_tags();
        if($tags):
            foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
            
                <dd>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>           
                </dd>
                
    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

    
    <?php 
    // Get Catergories NOT WORKING!
    
    $categories = get_the_category();

        foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
            <dd>
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>           
            </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php get_template_part('includes/section', 'result-slider'); ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you put `the_post()` in top of your template? Otherwise the current post ID might not be initialized and the correct categories aren't fetched. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/

Comment: Thanks @jrswgtr. Yes I did. Only on the archive-projects.php file as you can see above.

Comment: You should put it in top of your `single-projects.php` too, right after `<?php`

Comment: Thanks again. But still nothing. I've added the_post() after <?php and before the <?php $i = 1; ?>
                <?php while(have_rows('project_collection')): the_row(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of using this code block for your tag

```
 $tags = get_the_tags();
    if($tags):
        foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
        
            <dd>
                <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>           
            </dd>
            
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

try this code block. I think it will solve your problem

```
 $tags = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'Your tag/taxonomy slug name', array("fields" => "all"));
    if($tags):
        foreach($tags as $tag): ?>
        
            <dd>
                <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>           
            </dd>
            
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

explicitly to say instead of using ***get_the_tags()*** use ***wp_get_post_terms()*** function.
I hope this will solve your tag problem. :)

Comment: You are a star! It worked. I don't understand why get_the_tags() did not work. There's clearly something I'm missing and just can't see it. Thanks again.

Comment: Great. Please if it helps. accept the answer :)
can leave a vote for others who are looking for help for this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

AR. Arif, thank you a lot for this answer. It helped me to solve the next problem. I added categories for portfolio items. The are ok in admin panel, but the output on frontend was strange. Categories of one portfolio item were output near another item.

So i replaced this
$portfolio_categories = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category');

with this
$portfolio_categories = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category', array("fields" => "all"));

in theme's templates/taxonomy/categories-portfolio.php (in child theme of course)

and it works correctly finally.